# Text Field in Processing Language (Using CP5)

Tags: processing, textfield

How do I implement character limit where it will stop the user from typing in more than 3 chars? I could make my own filter but before I want to save some code by finding out if there is a built in method; Unfortunately, I have not come upon a method.

[Click here for the CP5 API for Processing](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/Textfield.html)
[image]

Comment: Can't you just intercept the event and ignore any events that would cause the text to go over the character limit?

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/11864/textfield-in-cp5

Comment: I'm just going to keep iterating the length of the current string within the text field. If it exceeds 3, I'll just ".setText()" it back to 3 characters.